# После закрывающей скобки может стоять тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

> Обычно на западной стороне храма (при условии, что он верно
>   ориентирован, а в древних городах это не всегда было возможно) –
>   важно, что напротив алтаря, там, куда смотрит священник, когда
>   обращается к пастве, – разыгрывается сцена Страшного суда.

Тире я нарисовала, иначе никак не читается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, конечно.
После закрывающей скобки могут стоять запятая, точка с запятой, двоеточие и **тире** (исключение в § 26 этого предложения не касается):

*Вся эта область (это недавно установили учёные) — дно моря в прошлом.*
[**Д. Э. Розенталь. § 67. Скобки и другие знаки**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=179#pp179)

Мне кажется, что надо заменить "что" на "чтобы". Посмотрите (без скобок):

**Обычно на западной стороне храма – важно, чтобы напротив алтаря, там, куда смотрит священник, когда обращается к пастве, – разыгрывается сцена Страшного суда.**

Comment: Сравните: *Обычно разыгрывается сцена. Важно, что это происходит напротив алтаря.*  <=> *Обычно разыгрывается сцена. Важно, чтобы это происходило напротив алтаря.* По-моему, пожелание *чтобы* не подходит к тому, что уже произошло и продолжает происходить.